# ViteJS (and MUI popper) causing Errors

Tags: vite

Having same [issue as this fella](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/8308). The issue was closed but the problem was not addressed (go figure!)

`styled_default is not a function`
Is the errors.

How to reproduce? Just use `Vite` and the `MUI Material Popper`

Vite completely barfs and shuts down.

Has anyone run into this issue and fixed it? At a dead end here..

Removing `node_modules`, clearning the npm/yarn cache, and all the other silly fixes are not doing the trick. Thanks yall!

Comment: I have this same problem and can’t seem to find a solution online.

Comment: I have also encountered this problem. The call stack is not presented anywhere, neither in the browser console nor in the terminal. The bad part is that sometimes it happens, sometimes not. And on some machines, it works on others it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue, and various fixes seem to help for a while, then the problem comes back. This is the [only permanent fix I have found](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32727#issuecomment-1335946124), though it's more of a hack:

> The only thing that helped me to get unblocked was to go to Popper.js file in node_modules (node_modules/@mui/material/Popper/Popper.js) and then commenting out this code
>
> ```
> //const PopperRoot = styled(PopperUnstyled, {
> //  name: 'MuiPopper',
> //  slot: 'Root',
> //  overridesResolver: (props, styles) => styles.root
> //})({});
> ```
>
> After that I had to replace PopperRoot with PopperUnstyled in the same file here
>
> ```
> const Popper = /*#__PURE__*/React.forwardRef(function Popper(inProps, ref) {
>   const theme = useTheme();
>   const props = useThemeProps({
>     props: inProps,
>     name: 'MuiPopper'
>   });
> // replace PopperRoot with PopperUnstyled
>   return /*#__PURE__*/_jsx(PopperUnstyled, _extends({
>     direction: theme == null ? void 0 : theme.direction
>   }, props, {
>     ref: ref
>   }));
> });
> ```

Then run `rm -Rf node_modules/.vite`.